# Split dataframe by unique values in column and create objects in global environment

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-manipulation

Data example.

```
date1 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)
date2= seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)
date3 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 29)
date4 = seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "month", length.out = 10)

subproducts1=rep("1",29)
subproducts2=rep("2",29)
subproductsx=rep("x",29)
subproductsy=rep("y",10)

b1 <- c(rnorm(29,5))
b2 <- c(rnorm(29,5))
b3 <-c(rnorm(29,5))
b4 <- c(rnorm(10,5))


dfone <- data.frame("date"= c(date1,date2,date3,date4),
                "subproduct"= 
                  c(subproducts1,subproducts2,subproductsx,subproductsy),
                "actuals"= c(b1,b2,b3,b4))
```

Question: How would I split dfone into 4 dataframes in global environment based off unique subproducts?

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from dumping variables into your global environment that have indexes in their names. It makes a lot of things much harder to work with in R. It's so much easier to keep related data objects in lists. For example you could just use `split()` on `dfone`, like `split(dfone, dfone$subproduct)`

Comment: `split(dfone, dfone$subproduct)`. Then, use `list2env` but pay atention no @MrFlick's comment.

Comment: Can someone explain to me why putting objects into glb environment is bad practice? In my case I am trying to automate/clarify code so it's easier for someone to look at or use in the future

Comment: The data will always be changing, although the format will be the same and the amount of modifications I need to do manually can be varying too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_split` from `dplyr` to return a `list` of data.frame/tibbles

```
library(dplyr)
dfone %>%
    group_split(subproduct)
```

It may be better to split into a `list` and do the transformations within the `list`.  But, global objects can be created by looping over the sequence of `unique` 'subproduct' elements, and then `assign` new objects ('subprod1', 'subprod2' ...) on the `subset` of data for that particular 'subproduct'

```
un1 <- unique(dfone$subproduct)
for(i in seq_along(un1)) 
     assign(paste0('subprod', i), subset(dfone, subproduct == un1[i]))
```

Comment: Can we also add these to global environment with some sort of name? Like subproduct1,subproduct2.. etc

Comment: @chriswang123456 do you want the updated one

Comment: In my real data, the names of subproduct are very long, is there a way to make custom names like subprod1 ... subprod100

Comment: @chriswang123456 try the update

Comment: Can you go to the comments that I posted above, not to this answer? In the case of automating/clarifying code for someone else to use... Wouldn't creating a bunch of list objects be difficult for someone who has never seen the code to use? If they wanted to reuse things and data will always be changing I think making global environment variables is the best solution.. Wanted to hear your thoughts

Comment: @chriswang123456 If you are creating 100s of objects in the global env, not a good choice.  Reasons - 1) you are creating this objects and then gathering those objects by applying some function.  The same can be done in a `list` if you loop over the list with `lapply` and apply the function.  2) Once the transformations are done, you may need to gather all objects again for writing back.  Here, also from a list it is easier.   Having said that it is all about your convenience.  If you are okay with global objects, go for it.  But, I wouldn't do that

Comment: I see. Currently if I give my code to someone else with list based solutions I don't think it would be obvious for them.. but maybe I'm wrong.  In the future I will work on making better list based solutions. Thanks for your wisdom and advice.